# Is there an official/academic name for the "current value" in a loop?

Tags: semantics

This is a question about semantics/vocabulary. I don't like saying "the current value you are looping over/on". I'm wondering if there is a better term.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've seen 'index' used most often for this, I think. That said, I agree with Tyler's answer, there is no standardized term and it's context dependent.

Comment: *loop variable* or *loop counter* (if iterating over numbers). See also Wikipedia [For loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official name for a variable used in a loop because it depends on how it is used and what it is used for. For instance, it could be a state, pointer, iterator, index, counter, flag, variable, etc. Each of these might have a more verbose name and can be used in a different capacity. Other than that, you could refer to it by "the variable used in the loop", "the loop variable", or maybe "the loop state".